# Не получается выполнить запрос на c# как в postman

Tags: c#, http, request, postman

С помощью Postman я делаю POST запрос на страницу [naurok.com.ua/test/join](http://naurok.com.ua/test/join). Этот запрос должен вернуть мне html страницу с тестами, точнее html, заготовленный под них. Всё прекрасно работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Content-Type:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Имя** можно любое.

**Код:** 775305.

**_csrf** можно найти в **head**-е страницы [naurok.com.ua/test/join](http://naurok.com.ua/test/join) (он каждый раз генерируется новый и действителен на протяжении пары часов)

Я пробовал сделать запрос с такими же хедерами и данными, однако в ответ сайт мне кидает ошибку 400.
После этого я решил скопировать код, сгенерированный Postman-ом для c#. Однако и он не работает корректно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из картинки:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://naurok.com.ua/test/join");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
// хедер постмэна я убрал, однако и с ним ничего не работает
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "_csrf=W9IiWC1pzG9kRnVcKhGyQCy77hlIZjgOtnRLRUcmJpQVh2khQBG6GCIAEDBdJ58ES83WeDwBe16BLj4ycm9KzA%3D%3D%3D%3D&JoinForm%5Bname%5D=test546&JoinForm%5Bgamecode%5D=775305", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
File.WriteAllText("./response.html", response.Content); // сохранения html ответа в файл
```

Прошу помочь разобраться, почему мой запрос на c# и в postman работают по-разному, и как исправить. Благодарю.

Comment: попробуй кидать запрос через HttpClient

Comment: Нет, это не чем не помогло

Comment: `делаю POST запрос на страницу` - Как вы его делаете? Лично я пока делал этот запрос в Postman добавил "куку", заголовок `UserAgent` и тело, где у вас это все в запросе? Тело вижу, ок, а кука, а `UserAgent`? Вам сайт при заходе дает куку с csrf, также сама страница содержит другую часть этого токена (заметьте, они разные), они оба должны быть при отправке запроса. Отправив их, вы получите 500 ошибку и тут начинайте перебирать заголовки, поймете, что не хватает `UserAgent`'a. Так что извините, но я без понятия как вы так "копируете" запрос... P.S. Настоятельно не советую копировать код postman

Comment: Я подробно описал как я делаю запрос. Могу повторить. Я захожу на сайт и из html беру сгенерированный токен csrf (ручной способ для простоты). Затем в постмэне в тело добюавляю заголовок, имя и код. И указываю ContentType. Всё. Postman прекрасно выполняет запрос. Если вам выпадает ошибка 500, то посто возьмитк csrf токен с это страницы с ошибкой.

Comment: Вы меня слышать не хотите, пойдем иначе: Postman сохраняет куку, а сайт ее генерирует по новой, при отправке любого запроса на него. Зайдите в [Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG0US.png) и удалите ее там, сработает ваш запрос? Я думаю, что нет, ибо защита от подмены работает именно так (требует 2 токена). А с ошибкой 500 - я сказал почему она и как решается, может сайт так реагирует на людей с другой страны, не знаю, но факт остается фактом и я вроде уже все сказал, что вам надо отправить.  P.S. Не забывайте оповещать через @ того, кому адресовано сообщение, иначе он не увидит уведомление.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поробовать кинуть реквест через другого клиента

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"https://naurok.com.ua/test/join");

    request.Headers.Clear();
    request.Headers.Add();
    // добавляешь хедеры в формате "<key>","<value>"
    ...

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.Content // используешь контент ответа
}
```

Comment: Нет, это не чем не помогло

Comment: может метод не post, а get? ничего не напутал?

Comment: нет, ничего не напутал